# Remove word/directory from URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Currently my single page URL looks like this:

```
http://website.com/post/6268/some-post-title
```

The post number and title are being generated using PHP. What I want to do is to remove the following part form the URL:

```
/post/6268/
```

so that it looks like this:

```
http://website.com/some-post-title
```

What I tried to do was to add the following line into the .htaccess file however it does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1
```

I have reviewed many questions here as well as some other forum topics I found but I was unable to find a solution on this.

The line in the .htaccess file actually states:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*)$ view.php?pid=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

The "removing a part of a URL" is completely ambiguous. Do you want to make it so the browser never sees this in their URL address bar eventhough they type in the URL *with* the directories you want removed? Do you want to only give them the shorter URL with the words removed and internally *add them back* so that the existing resource where the URL pointed to can serve the content, or is it that there are bad URL's floating around with the extra directories in the URL that you simply need to remove internally on the server so that the proper resource (sans the directories) can serve the content?

If it's the former, then you were sort of on the right track:

```
RewriteRule ^post/[0-9]+/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

For the last thing, you just need to remove the `R=301` flag from the square brackets. But for the 2nd thing, you're ditching the `6268` from the URL, and when the server sees a request for `/some-post-title`, it has no idea what that post ID is supposed to be.

Comment: The above is not working I'm afraid: I found that the line in my .htaccess file states:    RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*)$ view.php?pid=$1